# Django: How to render a specific HTML with context in an On Approve Ajax

Tags: python, django

In my Project after a Payment is made via PayPal I am trying to redirect it to an HTML page with certain context as per the following views:

```
def payment_complete(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    order = Order.objects.get(
        user=request.user, ordered=False, id=body['orderID'])
    payment = Payment(
        user=request.user,
        stripe_charge_id=body['payID'],
        amount=order.grand_total()
    )
    payment.save()

    order.payment = payment
    order.ordered = True
    order.ref_code = create_ref_code()
    order.save()
    messages.success(request, "Your Order was Successful ! ")
    return render(request, "order_completed.html", {'order': order})  <------------------------
```

I have tried adding but it took me the home while I am trying to go to an HTML that is created to show executed payment details

```
                // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
                window.location.replace("/");
```

Also, I tried but it didn't work

```
window.location.href = 'core:payment-complete';
```

Here is the full paypal on approve script

```
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                console.log(details);
                sendData();
                function sendData() {
                  fetch(url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                      "Content-type": "application/json",
                      "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ orderID: orderID, payID: details.id }),
                  });
                }
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
                window.location.replace("/");
                window.location.href = 'payment-complete';
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  </script>
```

Comment: First of all, are you sure this is a good approach to create payment  in your db without sever-side confirmation?

Comment: What do you mean is there a better approach?